# Segmentation Fault (core dumped) - vectors

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stdvector, coredump

I am working at algorithm which can calculate length of curve using elementary segments. So if I have vector of x and y coordinates of curve I need to calculate number of this elementary segments. I've invented my own recursive algorithm for that. There is a code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
//***********************************************
inline double Pitagoras(double xp, double yp, double xf, double yf)
{
    return sqrt((xp - xf)*(xp - xf) + (yp - yf)*(yp - yf));
}
//***************************************************
inline double calculateX(double xp, double yp, double a, double b, const double eps)
{
   double delta;
   double x1, x2;

     delta = (-2.0 * xp + 2.0 *a*b - 2.0 *a*yp)*(-2.0 * xp + 2.0 *a*b - 2.0 *a*yp)
        - 4.0* (1.0 + a*a)*(xp*xp + yp*yp + b*b - 2.0*b*yp - eps*eps);

     x1 = (-(-2.0 * xp + 2.0 *a*b - 2.0 *a*yp) - sqrt(delta))/(2.0 * (1.0 + a*a));
     x2 = (-(-2.0 * xp + 2.0 *a*b - 2.0 *a*yp) + sqrt(delta))/(2.0 * (1.0 + a*a));

   if(x1 >= xp)
     return x1;
     else
       return x2;
}
//***************************************************
inline double calculateY(double x, double a, double b)
{
  return a*x + b;
}
//***********************************************
unsigned long algorithmKolmogorow(double xp, double yp, double xf,
double yf, const double eps, vector<double> &vectorX, vector<double> &vectorY);
//***********************************************
int main()
{
    vector<double> vctrY; //vector of value of function
    vector<double> vctrX; //vector of x
    double xP,yP,xF,yF; //coordinates of two points on the curve
    const double Eps = 0.0001; //length of elementary line

      for(double x=1.0; x<=5 ;x +=0.001)
        {
          vctrX.push_back(x);
          vctrY.push_back(x*x); //f(x) = x^2
        }

    xP = vctrX[0];
    yP = vctrY[0];
    xF = vctrX[1];
    yF = vctrY[1]; //set beginning value

    cout<<algorithmKolmogorow(xP, yP, xF, yF, Eps, vctrX, vctrY)*Eps;

    return 0;
}
//***************************************************
unsigned long algorithmKolmogorow(double xp, double yp, double xf,
 double yf, const double eps, vector<double> &vectorX, vector<double> &vectorY)
{
    static unsigned long N; //licznik
    static unsigned long i = 1;
    double d;
    double a,b;

      d = Pitagoras(xp, yp, xf, yf);

         if(d >= eps){
            a = (yf - yp)/(xf - xp);
            b = yp - a*xp;
            xp = calculateX(xp, yp, a, b, eps);
            yp = calculateY(xp, a, b);
            N++;
         }

           else{
             i++;
             xf = vectorX[i];
             yf = vectorY[i];
             //cout<<i<<"\t"<<vectorX[i]<<"\t"<<vectorY[i]<<endl;
           }

             if(i < vectorX.size())
              N =  algorithmKolmogorow(xp, yp, xf, yf, eps, vectorX, vectorY);

return N;
}
```

In main as you can see, I'm setting x,y coordinates for parabolic function. When Eps is big for example Eps = 0.001 everything works. If I set smaller value like Eps = 0.0001 then I get error like in topic and program stop running. I've completely no idea why.

I can add any new informations which you need (about my compiler, IDE, OS etc).

Rafal

Comment: You never access the first or second elements of `vectorX` or `vectorY`. Is this intentional? Note that `xf = vectorX[i]` will always try to access the third element because `i` begins at `1`. Remember that vectors are 0 indexed.

Comment: When I run this, the static variable `i` in `algorithmKolmogorow` never gets incremented, so the `if` block at the end always evaluates true and results in infinite recursion.

Comment: In main function I set vectorX[0] and vectorX[1] for variable xP and xF. And I started from value i = 2, because before code which you citated is incrementation i++

Comment: Unrelated to the problem at hand, but you could use `std::hypot(xp-xf,yp-yf)` instead of manually doing the square root of the sum of those squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running out of stack space due to the recursion.

A quick hack around this is to raise the stack size using `ulimit` in the shell, e.g.

```
(ulimit -s unlimited; ./my_program)
```

The real fix however is to remove the recursion.  `algorithmKolmogorow` looks like it does tail-recursion only, which can always be converted to a loop:

```
unsigned long algorithmKolmogorow(double xp, double yp, double xf,
 double yf, const double eps, vector<double> &vectorX, vector<double> &vectorY)
{
    static unsigned long N; //licznik
    static unsigned long i = 1;
    double d;
    double a,b;

    while(true) {
      d = Pitagoras(xp, yp, xf, yf);

         if(d >= eps){
            a = (yf - yp)/(xf - xp);
            b = yp - a*xp;
            xp = calculateX(xp, yp, a, b, eps);
            yp = calculateY(xp, a, b);
            N++;
         }

           else{
             i++;
             if(i >= vectorX.size())
               return N;
             xf = vectorX[i];
             yf = vectorY[i];
             //cout<<i<<"\t"<<vectorX[i]<<"\t"<<vectorY[i]<<endl;
           }

    }

}
```

There also fixes the problem of accessing the vectors one element passed their bounds.

There are still some problems:

- `N` should be initialized
- `algorithmKolmogorow` can only be used once per program invocation.  Remove the `static` from `N` and `i` to fix that.

Comment: OK, when we set the while loop it's really works but I can't understand why N and i cannot be static? If there are static, program works properly.

Comment: @RafałApriasz Try using `algorithmKolmogorow` twice in a row, using different input data.  E.g. use `vctrY.push_back(0.5*x*x); //f(x) = (x^2)/2` the second time to initialize (don't forget `vctrX.clear(); vctrY.clear();` to remove the old values).  The if you comment out the first invocation of `algorithmKolmogorow` you get about 12.7508 with the new input data.  If you comment the first invocation back in, you get 24.3852 for that (as originally), but you get 24.3866 for the second invocation instead of 12.7508.

Answer (score 1):

```
         i++;
         xf = vectorX[i];
         yf = vectorY[i];
         //cout<<i<<"\t"<<vectorX[i]<<"\t"<<vectorY[i]<<endl;
       }

         if(i < vectorX.size())
```

That will exceed the bounds of the vector by 1.  Maybe you needed `if(i < vectorX.size()-1)`  or (noting the comment by AndyG) maybe you needed the `i++` to be below those two uses of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Your value for `Eps` is too small.  It causes the algorithm to progress too slowly, which means you run out of stack space before the calculation can finish.  I increased `Eps` to 0.005 and the code runs fine.  Not sure if it produces the right answer though; you'll have to check.

Also, you need to change these lines:

```
xf = vectorX[i];
yf = vectorY[i];
```

To this:

```
xf = vectorX[i-1];
yf = vectorY[i-1];
```

Otherwise you access past the last vector element on the last iteration.  You may also want to do a tolerance study on `Eps` to see how small it has to be to get an accurate calculation.

Comment: Now, I delete comment from:
       //cout<<i<<"\t"<<vectorX[i]<<"\t"<<vectorY[i]<<endl;

And program stop running not at the end but at value i =1674. I checked that vectorX[1674] and vectorY[1674] have values

Comment: The reason for this is also because you run out of stack space.  Your algorithm results in a large amount of recursion, which leaves very little room left on the stack for anything else.  As @ex-bart pointed out, you really need to eliminate the recursion, given the number of function calls you make to `algorithmKolmogorow`.